# Can't create games with pygame

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I make a game with python 2.5 and pygame.

but,I can't complete make.
because this errors occured.

```
C:\Python26\TypeType\src\dist\Main.exe:8: RuntimeWarning: use font: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pygame\font.pyd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "pygame\__init__.pyo", line 70, in __getattr__
NotImplementedError: font module not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "pygame\sysfont.pyo", line 253, in SysFont
RuntimeError: default font not found 'freesansbold.ttf'
```

Perhaps I think that the reason is because it used an object called sysfont. (Because I had the programs that did not use sysfont on an execute file and was able to start with the PC which was not installed Python in)
What's wrong .
 sorry I'm begginer.

**EDIT**
I can find Python2.5\Lib\site-packages\pygame\freesansbold.ttf

but same error occured..
Where may I copy freesansbold.ttf

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to simply load the font directly instead of using sysfont. Just use the pygame.font.Font class and directly load a ttf file. This will also make it easier to use py2exe, and you can choose exactly the font you want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the `freesansbold.ttf` file on your computer in an accessible fonts folder. This font should have come with Pygame in the `lib` directory.

Check the installation folder for your copy of Pygame, and if it's there, modify your Python installation's font path to include that directory. If not, you'll need to find a copy or download a newer version of Pygame.

Comment: I can find Python2.5\Lib\site-packages\pygame\freesansbold.ttf

but same error occured.. Where may I copy freesansbold.ttf

Comment: Try copying it to your system fonts folder, or adding the folder where it exists to your Python font path. See this thread for more info: http://echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=26064

Answer (score 0):

You probably found a solution but i want to give one for other.
Create you game with pygame. Then, unzip the librairy file.
Go to

> PythonX.X\Lib\site-packages\pygame and copy freesansbold.ttf

Back to your library file that you unzipped and go to

> library\pygame

Put freesansbold.ttf in and zip library.

Now, it's work ! :)