# OSError:unable to read font file

Tags: python

Importing pyGame with pycharm prompts that there is no pygame. font file and that font. py file is not found in the folde.OSError: unable to read font file 'D:\pycharm安装\lib\site-packages\pygame\freesansbold.ttf'

Comment: Please take some time to write your question body well. Your tons of syntax erros make hard to even read the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question about font availability in pyGame is covered by this question: ["Can't create games with PyGame"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896062/cant-create-games-with-pygame).
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying to put hyphens in 'freesansbold' like this:
`'free-sans-bold'`
or:
`'free-Sans-bold'`
or:
`'freeSans-bold'`
in fact, try every possible combination you can think of.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).